# If Else Inside For Loop in R

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

I need to create a if/else statement in the middle of a for loop in R.

I am trying to create a hypothetical phase 1 clinical trial with 3-3 design in R. I start with sample1 ~ binomial(3, x/10), with x starting at 1. If the sample1 = 0, increase x by 1 and take a sample again. When sample1 > 0, take a second sample, sample2 ~ binomial(3, x/10), at the same x value. If sample2=0, increase x, and take sample1 again. If sample2>0, print that x value. I want to do this 10 times and see what the x value for is. Below is my code.

```
reps <- 10
MTD <- numeric(reps)
for (i in 1:reps) {
  x <- 1
  sample1 <- rbinom(1, 3, x/10)
  if (sample1>0) {sample2 <- rbinom(1,3, x/10)
  if (sample2>0) {MTD[i] <- (x)} else x<- x+1}
  else x <-x+1
  }
MTD
```

Looking at the results, all I get are zeros so something is not right. Could someone please assist.
Thanks.

Comment: I get zeros and ones using the same code

Comment: On using the same code, I also got both zeros and ones. Just to add, you should set a specific seed, when working with functions which give random values, so that your output is reproducible.

Comment: But there shouldn't be any 0's because I thought I have x start at 1.

Comment: MTD only changes when sample2 > 0, if the 10 repetitions return a sample1 or sample2 equal to 0, MTD[i] remains unchanged (0) and the next loop starts.

Comment: Okay. I want it to keep on sampling (increasing x by 1) until sample2>0, save that x value in MTD[i], and then start the loop again (starting at x=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
reps <- 10
MTD <- numeric(reps)
x <- 1
i = 1
while (i < reps) {

    sample1 <- rbinom(1, 3, x/10)
    if (sample1>0) {
        sample2 <- rbinom(1,3, x/10)
        if (sample2>0) {
            MTD[i] <- (x)
            i = i+1
            x = 1
        } else {
            x <- x+1
        }
    } else {
        x <- x+1
    }
}
MTD
```

What these changes do is for every i, you will keep taking sample1 and sample2 until sample1 > 0 and sample2 >0. Only then the loop will change to i+1 and x is reset to 1.

Comment: Thank you! This seems to give me what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
MTD <- as.numeric(10)
sapply(seq(MTD), function(i)
    {
    sample1 <- sample2 <- rbinom(1, 3, i/10)
    if(sample1>0){
        sample2 <- sample1
    }else{
        sample2 <- i+1
    }
    if(sample2>0){
        sample2 <- sample1
    }else{
        sample2 <- i+1
    }
})
```

Well, I split sample1 and sample2 as independent parameters to make it difference as shows below.

```
MTD <- as.numeric(10)
sapply(seq(MTD), function(i)
    {
    sample1 <- rbinom(1, 3, i/10)
    sample2 <- rbinom(1, 3, i/10)
    if(sample1>0){
        sample2 <- sample1
    }else{
        sample2 <- i+1
    }
    if(sample2>0){
        res <- sample1
    }else{
        res <- i+1
    }; return(res)
})
```

Is it your desired result?